# Python: Create new column with condition and "contains"-Statement

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I want to create a new column of a string with a condition. Example:

```
from pandas import DataFrame
GoT = {'Old_Group': ['Jon Snow', 'Sansa Stark','Arya Stark','Robb Stark','Theon Greyjoy' ]}
df = DataFrame(GoT,columns=['Old_Group'])
```

The "New_Group" should check if the "Old_Group" contains the String "Stark" on whatever place and assign it to e.g. "Stark Family". If the condition "contains = 'Stark'" does not fit, then the "new_group" should be assigned to e.g. "other"

In SQL I would do it this way:

```
Select Old_Group
,case when Old_Group like '%Stark%' then 'Stark Family' else 'other' end as New_Group
from df
```

Thank you

Comment: Also you don't want to import pandas like that. When you do that you are only importing one thing from pandas which is the DataFrame function. You would be better off importing the full library to ensure you can you all DataFrame operations.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need:

```
df['New_Group'] = df['Old_Group'].apply(lambda x : 'Stark Family' if 'Stark' in x else 'other')

print(df)
```

Output

```
      Old_Group New_Group                                                                                                                     
0       Jon Snow     other                                                                                                                     
1    Sansa Stark     Stark Family                                                                                                                    
2     Arya Stark     Stark Family                                                                                                                    
3     Robb Stark     Stark Family                                                                                                                    
4  Theon Greyjoy     other
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use a combination of np.where and str.contains to do this. Essentially what you cant to do is apply np.where on the column in question (Old Group in this case) and the check if the string contains the work Stark.

```
df['New Group'] = np.where(df['Old Group'].str.contains("Stark"), 'Stark Family', 'Other')
```

Just make sure your column New Group is a string data type and you have numpy imported as a package

Comment: instead of importing numpy use `pd.np`

Comment: How will the compiler know that np is the package? It would think it is calling something else entirely. Risky imo

Comment: Can you link the source of that? I have never seen it before, looks cool!

Answer (score 1):

In case the name `Stark` appears in a name like MacStark, then this option would leave it out. Also it is case insensitive

```
df.assign(New_Column=df.replace({r'(?i)^((?!\bStark\b).)*$':'Other',r'(?i)\bStark\b':'Stark Family'},regex=True))
Out[319]: 
       Old_Group          New_Column
0       Jon Snow               Other
1    Sansa Stark  Sansa Stark Family
2     Arya Stark   Arya Stark Family
3     Robb Stark   Robb Stark Family
4  Theon Greyjoy               Other
```

Comment: A bit of overkill but I like it, never a bad time to start using regex.